# Bash language changed automatically from English to something else

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv, git-bash, miniconda

I use bash terminal in VSCODE. When ever I run the command to activate virtual environment [code:"conda activate .\env"][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vC6P.png) my terminal's language is changing to something else. How can i change it back to English?

Comment: The language isn't changing, it's printing garbage. Appears to be a corrupted install (or corrupt activation config). Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling conda?

Comment: actually every code is working with this garbage. the mkdir command, touch command everything. But cant figure why this language change happend

Comment: Again, the language hasn't changed. Something in the lower-level character interpretation has been corrupted. Reboot. Uninstall conda and reinstall.

Comment: okay I will try

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, CONDA environment is damaged. Please try to reinstall it